# ¿Cómo puedo crear una estructura JSON en C#?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

Estoy tratando de crear un archivo JSON para que sea inyectado a través de un WebService hacia un servicio de un tercero, el cual va a llenar datos en un formulario dinámico.

El tema es que la estructura que debo respetar, según las especificaciones del proveedor, por poner un ejemplo ya que el modelo tiene una mayor cantidad de valores a transmitir, es la siguiente:

```
{ "f": "546",
  "efs": { "1":"Ubicación",
           "2":"Categoría",
           "3":"Contacto",
           "4":"Celular" } }
```

He revisado varios artículos de referencia, pero al crear la clase que necesito no puedo utilizar números como tags/marcadores (si es que se llaman asi) y por ende me veo obligado a usar lo siguiente:

```
    public class form_addsModel
    {
       public string f { get; set; }
       public efsModel efs { get; set; }
    }

    public class efsModel
    {
        public string _1 { get; set; }
        public string _2 { get; set; }
        public string _3 { get; set; }
        public string _4 { get; set; }
    }
```

El resultado esperado no llega a ser el adecuado, y la verdad es que no sé que tan factible sea construir un JSON con esas características y restricciones planteadas por el proveedor.

Actualmente estoy trabajando en C# con Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No puedes nombrar variables/propiedades como números, pero puedes utilizar una estructura de datos como un [`IDictionary`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary):

```
public class form_addsModel
{
   public string f { get; set; }
   public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<int, string> efs { get; set; }
}

...
public void CrearJson()
{
    form_addsModel model = new form_addsModel();
    model.f = "...";
    model.efs = new Dictionary<int, string>()
    {
        { 1, "Ubicación" },
        { 2, "Categoría" },
        { 3, "Contacto" },
        { 4, "Celular" },
    }
    ...
}
```

Dentro de un `Dictionary` puedes recrear sin problemas la estructura **`key/value`** que reina en JSON, y te da la flexibilidad de usar también números para representar el "nombre" de cualquiera de los índices que encuentre. En el ejemplo, nada te detiene de usar en lugar de una pareja `int - string` una pareja `string - string` y usarla así:

```
IDictionary<string, string>();

{
    { "1", "Ubicación" },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Esta forma de trabajo con JSON me ha ayudado a comprender la versatilidad y la facilidad en como se maneja la información, no pensé que usando una declaración del tipo Dictionary pudiera ayudar tanto, la verdad es que soy nuevo en este ambito. Muchas gracias Kroneaux :)

Comment: @JuanManuelPalacios ¡Me alegra que sea de ayuda, tocayo! No podríamos entender el internet de hoy sin XML y JSON, es buena noticia que estés aprendiéndolo, ¡sigue así!

Comment: no sabía que eramos tocayos, mira tu. El mundo web sigue siendo un misterio para mí, ya que estoy acostumbrado a trabajar en cliente/servidor, la forma en como se desarrollan las páginas web están aún fuera de mi alcance, al menos por el momento :)

Answer (score 3):

Si como comentaban para estos casos usaríamos un `Dictionary<int, string>`

```
public class claseEjemplo
{
    public int f  { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string> efs { get; set; }

    public claseEjemplo()
    {
        efs = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    }
}
```

Y para serializarlo a una cadena JSON usamos la libreria https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

```
claseEjemplo obj = new claseEjemplo();
obj.f = 546;
obj.efs.Add(1, "Ubicación");
obj.efs.Add(2, "Categoría");
obj.efs.Add(3, "Contacto");
obj.efs.Add(4, "Celular");

string miJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

Console.WriteLine(miJson);
```

Ejemplo en linea: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CpMStk

Comment: Muchas gracias Michael, tu ejemplo complementa mucho lo que quería hacer, apoyando la respuesta de Kroneaux, y agregando la secuencia de codigo de tu ejemplo, pude lograr una carga de datos limpia, realmente fue de gran ayuda :)